# Wrong keyboard mapping

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My backspace key acts like a ], and quote key acts like a backspace, etc. I was playing with layout settings in gnome, trying to fix another problem with layouts and got this one. How can I change my keyboard mapping, not language layout, back to normal?

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally turned on NICOLA-F style Backspace. Turning it down fixed the problem

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)